# how to capture GTalk data with Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, google-talk

im working in a IVTR via Asterisk and gtalk chat (using the chat box in gmail ) , the configuration of gtalk account and jabber are working almost perfectly except when i want capture data from the chat.

Using `JABBER_RECEIVE` method i'm able to capture chat text but if nothing was received and the timeout is over, Asterisk crash.

i've no idea of what's going on , is  there another way (method or  agi) to capture gtalk chat in Asterisk without crashing?

i'm using Asterisk 1.8.3 in CentOS 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "capture gtalk chat".

If you want to display - for debugging purposes only - the XMPP messages that are sent to/from GTalk, you can use "jabber set debug on".  This will dump as DEBUG messages to the Asterisk logs/CLI all XMPP messages.

Crashes are a "bad thing".  While res_jabber in Asterisk 1.8 is a community support module, you may still want to report any crashes to the [public issue tracker](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira).  Since this is a crash, you'll be asked to provide a properly generated backtrace - instructions for doing so can be found on [this wiki page here.](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+a+Backtrace)